# Xorg seems to kill EC2 instances (CentOS 5.4)

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, xorg, xvfb

My end goal is to run firefox in headless mode with xvfb.
But Xvfb requires Xorg, and I'm running into a problem with Xorg.

When I fire up an instance using this AMI:

ami-4a24d623
RightImage_CentOS_5.4_i386_v5.5.9_EBS

Then do:

```
yum install Xorg
```

Then reboot the instance, I get failed status checks, and I can't log into the instance.
Server Logs (Instance Actions->Get Server Log) are blank.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to configure Xorg somehow?

Comment: Turns out I did not need Xorg, just Xvfb.  
You may get errors like this when running Xvfb:

    Couldn't open RGB_DB '/usr/share/X11/rgb'
    _XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
    _XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/domU-12-31-39-04-48-DD:99
    

A link elsewhere on the interwebs says (correctly) that installing Xorg will eliminate some of these errors.
Turns out I was able to just ignore the errors, and my application still did what it needed to.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled SElinux which helped me bring instance up